# Getting the selected item in android wheelview

Tags: android

I'm using a Wheelview in my android app as a Datepicker, and I need to get the selected item for example "January". I tried the getCurrentItem() but I guess it only get the item position not the exact text.

here is my codes

```
WheelView wheelview = new (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.wheelview1);
String[] ampArray = new String[] {"January", February", "March"}
ArrayWheelAdapter<String> amp = new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this, ampArray);
wheelview.setViewAdapter(amp);
wheelview.getCurrentItem();
```

can anyone have a better way regarding his?
thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide some code?

Comment: you can see [this](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/advanced-android-ui-wheelpicker/) example for getting selected text from wheelview

Comment: I can't used this line  text1.setText(wheelMenu1[getWheel(R.id.p1).getCurrentItem()]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get Current Text from WheelView as:

```
String strselected_txt=ampArray[wheelview.getCurrentItem()];
```

Comment: Sir did you know how to display images using wheelview? or any links?

Comment: @GangnaminmoAko : k let me check if possible then i will give you right link

Answer (score 0):

```
protected WheelView getWheel(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
    }


String variable_name = (ampArray[getWheel(R.id.WheelView_Name).getCurrentItem()]);
```